# Remove absolute duplicates in each row of a data frame in R

Tags: r

I am trying to remove all the rows that have absolute duplicates in my data frame. Here is an example.

```
library(gtools)
vector <-  c(15.3, -31.8, -35.6, -14.5, 3.1,-24.5)
vector.combo <- data.frame(combinations(n = 12, r = 6, v = c(vector,-vector)))
```

When you run the above command, you will basically have a data frame containing all of the unique combinations of the elements of "vector" and "-vector". For instance, you will see something like this:

```
-35.6   -31.8   -15.3   -3.1    3.1   35.6
```

Now, I want to remove all the rows that contain the absolute duplicates, meaning I want to remove the rows that has elements such as "35.6" and "-35.6".

I try this:

```
vector.combo[!duplicated(abs(vector.combo)),]
```

but it did not work.

Any tip would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you are asking for. Could you use a smaller input data and show what you expect as a result in the form of an actual data frame? Are you looking for rows that are unique in terms of absolute values they include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using dplyr:

```
library(gtools)
library(dplyr)

vector <-  c(15.3, -31.8, -35.6, -14.5, 3.1,-24.5)
vector.combo <- data.frame(combinations(n = 12, r = 6, v = c(vector,-vector)))
dup_idx <- 
  vector.combo %>% 
  transmute_all(abs) %>% 
  duplicated()

vector.combo[!dup_idx,]
```

Regards
Paweł

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the below:

```
library(gtools)
vector <-  c(15.3, -31.8, -35.6, -14.5, 3.1,-24.5)
vector.combo <- data.frame(combinations(n = 12, r = 6, v = c(vector,-vector)))

unique_combo <- vector.combo[apply(abs(vector.combo), 1, function(x) length(unique(x))) ==6,]
```

The index goes row by row over the absolute value of the table, and counts how many unique elements. If the number of unique elements is 6, it returns a true, otherwise a false. We then use that as an index to `vector.combo`.

Comment: Thank you. I made a function by myself but your function is more efficient.

Comment: @AdamRalphus : please be sure to upvote the answer or mark it as correct to close it out. This way other people know the preferred way and the poster gets credit.

Answer (score 0):

```
get_rid <- c()
for ( i in 1 : length(vector.combo[,1]) ) {
    if ( length(unique(abs(vector.combo[i,]))) != 6 ) {
    get_rid <- c(get_rid, i)
    }
}
vector.combo <- vector.combo[-get_rid,]
```

That should do it.